# Input caret stops blinking in Chrome when d3 animation applied

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, d3.js

I have a problem with caret not blinking in the input field. Caret at first blinks in the input field, but after you start typing it will freeze. This happens only if I have running animation on element. Animation is just switching fill color. I have prepared this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4bqkP/17/

```
function setNewAnimation(){
    if (d3.select('.polyRect').attr('fill')=='#ff0000'){
        d3.select('.polyRect')
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr('fill', '#00ff00')
            .each("end", setNewAnimation);
    }
    else{
        d3.select('.polyRect')
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr('fill', '#ff0000')
            .each("end", setNewAnimation);
    }
}
```

This only happens in Chrome and Opera. Firefox and IE works ok.

Any clue?

Comment: I found out something more. Problem occurs only when polygon have set stroke property or stroke-width property. I have prepared one more fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bqkP/18/ that works OK until I have commented this two lines     //.attr("stroke","black")
//.attr("stroke-width",1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not a issue any more in newer version of Chrome. Tested in Chrome Version 66.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an experiment using Chrome's timeline tool (under dev tools) on the revision 20 of your fiddle.

I made a few change, to trigger the animation then stop it to highlight when the browser have time to paint its caret.

[image: XP Result]

On the beginning of the selected section, this is your animation and its paint (green squaring) : I've observed that the browser never repaint the caret of the textfield meanwhile.

After your selection ended, the browser repaints the whole textfield (the paint 164x20) and then, ± 500ms after, the animation of the caret goes on, and is repainted (blue arrow).

**In the case of your updated Fiddle, it's the same thing, the caret doesn't even seems to be painted by the browser nor the textfield.**

The stroke thing might be a good guess, I took a look in [Webkit sources](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/af9ccddaac56937888195fa020c0ec2550a4874e/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderObject.cpp) on rendering objects, searched for all "stroke" occurrences in the document : It could lead to something!

I assume for the moment that it is internal painting optimization of Webkit (not tested on Opera) that messes around - I will get deeper in this later!

Comment: It looks like Chrome does not have time to repaint the caret. If I change my fiddle to non continuous animation, then caret get repainted sometimes. One conterminously running animation causes that caret is not blinking in any of my input fields in the whole application, also the ones that were not changed. Strange is that this problem occurs only after start typing into input, before that works ok and that this problem occurs when element (polygon, rectangle,..) have stroke.

Comment: Any resolution on this? I am getting it but I don't know the cause, it does happen when you begin to type, and once it happens its permanent for all input elements.

Comment: @MarkRobbins Unfortunately, no : I didn't dig it through webkit's sources.